Randomly Forced Fractal Process and Its Invariant Measure
Consider a process on $[0,1]$ that builds a limit function $F$ through iteration. At stage $n$, partition $[0,1]$ into $2^n$ equal subintervals. On each subinterval, assign a random value $\xi_n = \pm1$ with probability $p$ for $+1$ and $1-p$ for $-1$. Scale this $n$th level forcing by $\alpha^n$ where $\alpha\in(0,1)$ is fixed. The limit function is then:
$$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \alpha^n \xi_n(x)$$
where $\xi_n(x)$ denotes the random $\pm1$ value assigned to the dyadic interval containing $x$ at level $n$. Almost surely, this random series converges to a fractal-like function $F$. Define a dynamical system:
$$T_F(x) = x + \beta\,F(x) \pmod{1}$$
where $\beta\in(0,1)$. Does there exist, for almost every realization of $F$, a $T_F$-invariant probability measure? If so, under what conditions is this measure absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure rather than singular?
I tried analyzing how small-scale geometry (encoded by the random forcing) interacts with the global mixing properties of $T_F$. My first attempt was to prove existence of invariant measures by approximating $T_F$ with finite-scale versions using just the first $N$ terms of $F$ and applying compactness arguments.
To control absolute continuity, I attempted to bound how the jumps from $F$ spread mass in $[0,1]$. I found that if $\beta$ is too large relative to how quickly $\alpha^n$ decays, the transformation appears to concentrate mass around certain dyadic rationals. For small $\beta$, I suspect the random kicks at each scale create enough mixing to spread mass evenly, but proving this using either spectral methods or large deviations has eluded me.
